# 00907. 00000 - "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

```
create table Funkcje
(
  nazwa_funkcji varchar(15) constraint funk_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  min_myszy number(5) funk_min_nn NOT NULL,
  max_myszy number(5) funk_max_nn NOT NULL,
  constraint funk_ch check(min_myszy < max_myszy)
)
```

I am getting an error while creating Table Orders:

> ORA-00907 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to name a NOT NULL constraint in line you need to use the constraint keyword as with every other type of constraint

```
create table Funkcje
(
  nazwa_funkcji varchar(15) constraint funk_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  min_myszy number(5) constraint funk_min_nn NOT NULL,
  max_myszy number(5) constraint funk_max_nn NOT NULL,
  constraint funk_ch check(min_myszy < max_myszy)
)
```

This returns the following in the data dictionary

```
SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_type, search_condition_vc
  2    from user_constraints
  3   where table_name = 'FUNKCJE';

CONSTRAINT_NAME      C SEARCH_CONDITION_VC
-------------------- - -----------------------
FUNK_MIN_NN          C "MIN_MYSZY" IS NOT NULL
FUNK_MAX_NN          C "MAX_MYSZY" IS NOT NULL
FUNK_CH              C min_myszy < max_myszy
FUNK_PK              P
```

Also, although varchar and varchar2 are identical Oracle doesn't guarantee that the current behaviour of varchar will continue (it's been the same for a very long time though). It would be more usual to use varchar2. [The documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020):

> Do not use the VARCHAR data type. Use the VARCHAR2 data type instead.
>   Although the VARCHAR data type is currently synonymous with VARCHAR2,
>   the VARCHAR data type is scheduled to be redefined as a separate data
>   type used for variable-length character strings compared with
>   different comparison semantics.